# How to design an interface returning another interface type which could only be fulfilled emergent

Tags: go, interface, architecture

Short premise:
I try to design a package which holds several types fullfilling the same set of interfaces and another package working with these interfaces. Now I'm puzzled how to fulfill an interface returning another interface type.

longer:
To be more specific: I've got two protocol / message types (broadcast / direct) which I want to be able to package to be transported by http/json and amqp/rabbit. My "transport"-packages (json and amqp) require my message-packages (dm/broadcast) to fulfill / present some information: e.g. `GetAddress` or `NewResponse`. For `NewResponse` my message format generates, out of it's metainformation,a ResponseMessage. My transporter knows how to translate `GetAddress` to a useful routing information. There is my interface problem: Now I'm puzzled how to fulfill an interface returning another interface type.

```golang
type Addresser interface {
    GetRecipientAddress() string
}

type Responder interface {
    NewResponse() (Responder, error)
}

type DM struct {
}

func (dm *DM) GetRecipientAddress() string {
    return ""
}

func (dm *DM) NewResponse() (*DM, error) {
    return dm, nil
}
```

As long as my `(dm *DM) NewResponse` returns `Responder` the `Responder` interface is fulfilled. When I return `*DM`, which fulfills `Responder`, `*DM` doesn't fulfill `Responder`.

I kind of see that this seems to be an chicken or the egg problem, as long as I return `*DM`, `*DM` doesn't fulfill `Responder`, but "de facto" it fulfills it.

That leeds my to my assumption: I try to implement a bad design for the use of interfaces. Can somebody point me in the direction golang-gurus would solve this problem?

I thought maybe this could be a solution, but it seems to be just as flawed

```golang
type AddressResponder interface {
    Addresser
    Responder
}

func (dm *DM) NewResponse() (AddressResponder, error) {
    return dm, nil
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with using `func (dm *DM) NewResponse() (Responder, error)`?

Comment: Note that the two signatures `func() (*DM, error)` and `func() (Responder, error)` are simply two different types. It does not matter that `*DM` implements `Responder`, the one type is still different from the other.

Comment: "*DM doesn't fulfill Responder, but "de facto" it fulfills it." This is common misconception regarding interface signatures in Go: Interface signatures must match "verbatim". If NewResponse returns anything else than Responder it does not match the Responder interface. (No co/contravariance in Go.)

Comment: @Volker do you have a source for that? SInce it explains the behaviour und my misconception.

Comment: @mkopriva my problem is that my *DM fulfills more than that one interface and i want to use the return value possibly as all of these interfaces. Your second comment falls in line with Volkers comment, so I think this is the route of my misconception

Comment: @huehnerhose: Yes, the language Spec. If you read about interfaces and implements you see that the signatures must _match_, the response types must be the same (and not only asignable to each other).

Answer (score 2):

See [Type identity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity):

> **Two interface types are identical** if they have the same set of methods with the same names and **identical function types**. Non-exported method names from different packages are always different. The order of the methods is irrelevant.
>
> **Two function types are identical** if they have the same number of parameters and result values, corresponding parameter and **result types** are identical, and either both functions are variadic or neither is. Parameter and result names are not required to match.

---

Try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/8g5AxkCyF8_g):

```
// NewResponse returns  (Responder, error)
func (dm *DM) NewResponse() (Responder, error) {
    return dm, nil
}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/TsC1KeIbQXU
If you look at this addition: I can't use the return value of `NewResponse` as Responder, since *DM does not fulfill `Responder`

Answer (score 1):

type `DM` can only fill `Responder` if and only if it has the methods described in `Responder`. I understand what you are saying, but this is how Golang works!

In other words, `DM` must have the method of signature `NewResponse() (Responder, error)` or else it does NOT implement `Responder`.

Thus perhaps you must change the definition to:

```
type DM struct {
}

func (dm *DM) NewResponse() (Responder, error) {
    return dm, nil
}
```